# How to create a perfect forwarding constructor for a tuple-like variadic class

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

I am trying to create thing similar to tuple, but I have come across a problem for writing my constructor.

Here is the code:

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename... Ts>
struct B {
    template <typename... ArgTypes>
    explicit B(ArgTypes&&... args)
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) == sizeof...(ArgTypes),
            "Number of arguments does not match.");
    }
};

struct MyType {
    MyType() = delete;
    MyType(int x, const char* y) {}
};

int main()
{
   B         <int, char>               a{2, 'c'};                      // works
   B         <int, bool, MyType, char> b{2, false, {4, "blub"}, 'c'};  // fails
   std::tuple<int, bool, MyType, char> t{2, false, {4, "blub"}, 'c'};  // works
}
```

Now, this works ok if pass simple types as initializers, but it does not, if I try to pass arguments in a brace-enclosed initializer list for non-trivial object.

GCC-4.7 emits the following:

```
vararg_constr.cpp:21:67: error: no matching function for call to 'B<int, bool, MyType, char>::B(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
vararg_constr.cpp:21:67: note: candidates are:
vararg_constr.cpp:6:14: note: B<Ts>::B(ArgTypes&& ...) [with ArgTypes = {}; Ts = {int, bool, MyType, char}]
vararg_constr.cpp:6:14: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 4 provided
```

Clang-3.1 the following:

```
vararg_constr.cpp:21:40: error: no matching constructor for initialization of
      'B<int, bool, MyType, char>'
   B         <int, bool, MyType, char> b{2, false,{4, "blub"}, 'c'};  // fails
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
vararg_constr.cpp:6:14: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2
      arguments, but 4 were provided
    explicit B(ArgTypes&&... args)
```

Ok, now what makes me very, very curious is that it works for tuple! According to the Standard (20.4.2.1) it has a constructor, that looks pretty much like mine.

```
template <class... Types>
class tuple {
public:
    // ...

    template <class... UTypes>
    explicit tuple(UTypes&&...);

    // ...
};
```

When constructing the tuple object in the same way, it works!

Now I would like to know:

A) What the hell? Why is std::tuple so special, and why don't compilers deduce the correct number of arguments?

B) How can I make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A) Why should the Compiler know, that `{4, "blub"}` is of type MyType and not `tuple<int, const char*>`?

B) Change ArgTypes to Ts in the constructor:

```
explicit B(Ts&&... args)
```

Tuple does also have the following constructor:

```
  explicit constexpr tuple(const _Elements&... __elements);
```

**EDIT**: The point is, that the constructor with const& is called and not that with the R-Values.  Consider the following:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct B {
  explicit B(const Ts&... elements) { std::cout << "A\n"; }
  template<typename... As,
           typename = typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(As) == sizeof...(Ts)>::type>
  explicit B(As&&... elements) { std::cout << "B\n" ;}
};

int main()
{
  MyType m {1, "blub"};
  B<int, char>           a{2, 'c'};                            // prints B
  B<bool, MyType, char>  b{false, {4, "blub"}, 'c'};           // prints A
  B<bool, MyType, MyType>c{false, {4, "blub"}, std::move(m)};  // prints A
}
```

Comment: A) How does the compiler know for the tuple constructor that it's a tuple and not MyType? 

B) Sorry, I should have elaborated on tuple a little. Tuple is parametrized on Ts..., but the constructor I am talking about is additionally parametrized on UTypes... .

Comment: Note that for part A, putting `&&` on the parameters of the enclosing template changes the meaning so it's no longer perfect forwarding, but will (barring reference arguments to `Ts`) form rvalue references, which are not desired. For part B, the rvalue references are "corrected" to lvalue `const &` so it will usually work, but it's still not perfect forwarding.

Comment: To expand on what Potatoswatter said, the usual solution is to write a constructor taking `T... t`, and then initialize the members from `std::forward<T>(t)...`. To convince yourself that it works, 'instantiate' the template (in your head :p) with `T` being a type, an lvalue reference, an rvalue reference and with its initializer being an lvalue then an rvalue. All situations will work and only the one where `T` is a type initialized from an lvalue results in a situation where one construction is superfluous. To avoid that means writing more than one constructor with a heavy dose of SFINAE.